# POJO to xslt-object

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I try to set POJO as Transformer parameter. But nothing turns out.

My POJO:

```
public class Certificate {

    private String serialNumber;
    private String owner;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date validFrom;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date validTo;
}
```

Setting POJO as parameter:

```
transformer.setParameter("userCertificates1", userCertificates.get(0));
```

XSLT-template:

```
<xsl:param name="userCertificates1" />
...
<div class="certificate-data">Сертификат<xsl:value-of select="$userCertificates1/serialNumber"/>
```

When processing, I have message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xpath.objects.XObject cannot be cast to org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet
```

Comment: Why would you expect Xalan to  expose Java properties as XPath child elements?

Comment: I need to use objects in xslt. Way not matters.

Comment: Are you aware of https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ex-java-namespace

Comment: no_____________